# What is inside the "other" category in the storage settings and how can I delete these large files eating my storage space?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4, storage, lineageos, 7.1-nougat

I know this question has been asked before, but I cannot find a clear answer.

I just recently flashed lineage is 14 on my Samsung galaxy S4. I used TWRP to wipe the internal storage with eh wipe internal storage option in the wipe menu.

So every now and then I go into settings and look at the storage tab, and I see how much storage apps and photos and so take up on the phone. And when I scroll down a see a category labled "other":

[image: "other"]
<sup>(click image for larger variant)</sup>

In this other category I see that around 700mb is taken up by this, and I don't know what is taking it up. I went to the explore option and there was nothing in there that could possibly take up 700mb.

So my question is what is in the other category, why does it keep growing, why do I need these files (if I do need them) and how can I delete them?

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 1):

Other section has all the remaining extension files e.g. Zip, rar, log, backup etc. You can remove these manually or you can use some app like ES File Explorer which can scan storage and recommend some files to delete.

Comment: Where do these files come from? How were they created?

Comment: You downloaded some zip e.g. LOS14.zip and logs are created by many apps and by recovery too.